# simultaneous edits to xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, overwrite

I am working on an application that reads and makes edits to an xml file but using the XDocument class Load() and Save() methods. If another application, or another instance of my application is running then one document could potentially overwrite changes that the other has made if it's in memory xdocument is not continually updating (reLoading). The simultaneous running programs would never edit the same section of the xml file at the same time.  What is the best way to solve this problem? Should I just do a Load right before I make every change or is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: can you lock the file while editing, or may be use single instance of the file??

Comment: @Priya10  single instance does not guarantee thread safety.

Comment: @pnya: Locking the file won't help, you need to unlock sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution would be not to use XML.

Use a (small) database.

Using any kind of text file in a multi-user situation is difficult enough and the fact that it is to different sections can only be used profitable if you have fixed-length and (therefore) fixed-position records (lines). XML does not deliver this.

Doing a load-before-edit will only make problems appear less often. There always is the chance that changes will be lost, you will have race-conditions at the filesystem level. To make it work you have to use a scheme with locking files. You will need an extra file for this.

Comment: like sqlite, there is an ado.net dataprovider for it: [System.Data.Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: @Femaref This application would be getting deployed on many machines. How difficult is the process of installing sqlite on the target machine and creating the database?

Comment: @Femaref How much of an increase in size will my program be?

Comment: You can also use SQL Server Express or Compact Edition, for more power than SQLLite.

Comment: @Jordan: This (sqlite/sqlce/...) has been asked before. Search the site and post a new question if you can't find something.

Comment: You will need to supply at least one library (System.Data.Sqlite.dll and System.Data.Sqlite.Linq.dll if you want to use Linq). Those aren't really large (both about 1 mb each). After that, only the size of the database will matter, as a comparision, I switched from using xml to sqlite in an application, I saw about 90% decrease in size.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about multiple processes being able to modify the file. If you want to keep the file instead of putting that data into a common store (MS SQL) you will need to implement a mutex to make sure only one application can access file at any moment of time.